# "In Folder" Field in Outlook 2010 doesn't show actual folder name

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have all of my emails in an Outlook Data File (pst), to make searching as flexible as possible, because search folders don't really work across files.  I have many folders and subfolders.

When using Conversation View, for example, I have emails showing up from other folders, which is good.  But the "In Folder" field does not show me what folders they are coming from.  Only the name of the Outlook Data File shows up.

This isn't helpful, since I only use 1 outlook data file.  And there doesn't seem to be any other field to represent what folder the email is in.  This field should really be named something else, and "In Folder" should be the folder it is in.

I can't find a workaround.  Either different field that gives me what I'm looking for, or a setting to change, or a way to create a custom field to do this, or something, would be welcomed.

It's not just conversation view either, but that's where I want it to work.

I'm not sure, but I think this worked in Outlook 2007 (conversation view didn't support pulling emails from other folders, unless used from a search folder).

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: I have the same problem and I would really like to find a solution for this. Unfortunately in all my web searches I didn't find and answer and as this question have been left unanswered for so long - I assume this isn't solvable.

Comment: I haven't solved it.  If I get some free time (not anytime soon), I might try messing around in vba or whatnot to maybe write the email's current folder into a custom field, and then display that custom field.  Not sure if that's possible or not, but seems like the best chance.

Comment: I did find a complicated way to do this in the VBA.  It is still a bit buggy, and if I can't find a simpler way, I'll further pursue this solution, and publish the code and steps to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot test conversation view today but this bit of VBA works elsewhere.

http://vboffice.net/sample.html?lang=en&mnu=2&smp=65&cmd=showitem

```
Public Sub GetItemsFolderPath()
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim F As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Msg$
    Set obj = Application.ActiveWindow
    If TypeOf obj Is Outlook.Inspector Then
        Set obj = obj.CurrentItem
    Else
        Set obj = obj.Selection(1)
    End If
    Set F = obj.Parent
    Msg = "The path is: " & F.FolderPath & vbCrLf
    Msg = Msg & "Switch to the folder?"
    If MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = F
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou for taking the time to answer.  I do already have a way to do this using vba, but, I am trying to get it to show up in the view, so that I can quickly see without clicking, where all of the emails are located.  The view supports a field called "In Folder", but it doesn't show the folder name for me, just the outlook data file name.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create custom field based on the formula.

RMB on **Columns** names bar -> **Customize current view** -> **Fields** -> **New Field**

- set **Name** as NEW In Folder
- set **Type** as Formula
- set **Fromula** as [In Folder]

(Formula with brackets)

Click OK, OK, OK.

New column should appear. If it will not show the folder name as you would expect, check if you have correct permissions in the folder (for example if you are delegate).

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I tried that, and it gives the same problem: it shows the data file name.  These emails are all in a data file, not the main outlook mailbox folders.  Also, I'm not a delegate (as far as I know), and I don't know if I have correct permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about conversation view, but in Outlook 2010 (and some of the earlier versions), using a Search folder you can see the name of the folder which actually holds the message in the "In Folder" column.

Would a Search Folder provide you with what you need?

The Search Folders can have their messages grouped by conversion if you use the view settings dialog.  However, "conversation" seems to be the same as "subject".